# visual studio 2017 installation failed

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have downloaded visual studio 2017 enterprise setup. Installation is fails while installing "**Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNetDiagnosticPack.Msi**"

I am trying to install it on windows 8.1 (x64)

following is the error log

```
The product failed to install the listed workloads and components due to one or more package failures.

Incomplete workloads
    .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26208.0)
    ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26208.0)

Incomplete components
    ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Container development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
    JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)

You can search for solutions using the information below, modify your selections for the above workloads and components and retry the installation, or remove the product from your machine.

Following is a collection of individual package failures that led to the incomplete workloads and components above. To search for existing reports of these specific problems, please copy and paste the URL from each package failure into a web browser. If the issue has already been reported, you can find solutions or workarounds there. If the issue has not been reported, you can create a new issue where other people will be able to find solutions or workarounds.

Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNetDiagnosticPack.Msi,version=15.0.30223.0' failed to install.
    Search URL: https://aka.ms/VSSetupErrorReports?q=PackageId=Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNetDiagnosticPack.Msi;PackageAction=Install;ReturnCode=1603
    Impacted workloads
        .NET desktop development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop,version=15.0.26208.0)
        ASP.NET and web development (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Impacted components
        ASP.NET and web development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Container development tools (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools,version=15.0.26208.0)
        JavaScript and TypeScript language support (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript,version=15.0.26208.0)
        Windows Communication Foundation (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.0.26208.0)
    Log
        C:\Users\Sagar\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_setup_20170830001200_003_Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNetDiagnosticPack.Msi.log
    Details
        MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.AspNetDiagnosticPack.Msi,version=15.0.30223.0\AspNetDiagnosticPack.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1" 
        Return code: 1603
        Return code details: Fatal error during installation.`
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: install on Windows 10

Comment: thanks for suggestion. but i have win 8.1. it will not be installed on win 8.1?

Comment: if i upgrade win 8.1 to 10, will i lose my data ie data on my win8.1 desktop, download folders, other files...

Comment: no, you shouldn't lose

Comment: but actually it can be installed on Windows 8.1 (with Update 2919355): Core, Professional, and Enterprise. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs

Comment: Try taking a look at these two links to see if they help:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/58570/cant-install-vs-2017.html
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/71871/view.html

Comment: I have already checked these sites. but no answer on this too.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this problem? New occurrence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350